# Windows PC to act as removable USB OTG drive for Android

Tags: linux, windows-10, usb-flash-drive, android

I have posted this question here than AndroidSE because I expect the answer to be actions on the PC.

TWRP recovery is a fantastic tool capable of dumping and restoring entire device images. If you want to dump your ROM you can do that to the device's internal or external SD storage, or to a USB OTG storage as soon as you can mount it into TWRP.

If the device doesn't have a removable SD storage **and** I want to dump the internal storage to make a perfect image, it starts to be a pain when using the target device to make an image of the device itself (e.g. `/sdcard/0` to `/sdcard/0` itself).

Since I have plenties of HDD storage **and** I want to save the few dozen bucks to buy a USB stick larger than the mobile device plus the OTG micro-USB cable, here comes the motivation for my question

> Is it possible to trick a PC (possibly running Windows) into sharing a folder via USB as if it was a thumb drive?

I know that if I connect an unlocked Android device I can browse the Android SD card from PC via MTP. No, that's not what I want.

I know that TWRP can show the device via USB so that PC can read its file system. No, that's not what I want.

I want the mobile device to act as a master and PC to act as a slave. Android/TWRP device will be able to read and write from somewhere in the PC like if it was a thumb drive.

My favourite OS is Windows, but I can accept answers for Linux OSes as well. They will still save me money for cable and thumb drive.

Comment: You would first have to install a USB gadget port, i.e. a USB type B or C connector (along with a USB device controller).  PCs typically only have host ports, i.e. type A connectors.

Comment: are you just saying that software emulation is not enough? i thought that with some software tricking one could use the microusb port on the phone to pretend a pc is a tyoe b/c hardware thumb drive?